# Erro ao conectar no banco de dados usando o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wpf

Estou criando uma aplicação WPF, e decidi utilizar o EntityFramework para realizar as operações no meu banco. Criei um modelo de dados a partir de uma base já existente no meu MySQL Workbench, e o processo foi executado corretamente, exportando todas as tabelas e gerando um contexto para elas.

Entretanto, quando desejo realizar qualquer tipo de operação na aplicação, como inserir dados em uma tabela, por exemplo, o programa trava e é encerrado automaticamente (sem dar qualquer mensagem de erro). E os dados também não estão sendo armazenados no banco.

O código que está dando erro é o seguinte:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (maisfilmesEntities ctx = new maisfilmesEntities())
        {
            usuario u = new usuario
            {
                login = "Teste",
                senha = "teste"
            };
            ctx.usuario.Add(u);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

As exceções geradas:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): The host localhost does not support SSL connections.
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
em MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher <Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
```

Erro capturado com o try/catch:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: Editei o post com a exceção completa.

Comment: eu estou usando mysql em um projeto, para usar eu tive que instalar no meu projeto esses pacotes, [aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) e [aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/7.0.7-m61)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você só precisa adicionar `SslMode=none` na sua connection string.

Veja um exemplo:

```
string connectionString = "ServerDoMeuBD;Database=MeuBD;Uid=Usuario;Pwd=Senha;SslMode=none;";
```

Leia mais sobre as [opções da connection string do MySQL aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-6-10-connection-options.html).